# What is best way to call a function if there no response from showDialog after x seconds in Futter

Tags: flutter, showdialog

I'm kinda new to flutter.  I searched but couldn't find a suitable answer to this...  What would be the best way to call a function if the user doesn't respond to a showDialog alert after x seconds?  If the user presses a button, then I don't want the function to execute.

Comment: You can use [Timer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Timer-class.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start a `Timer` for x seconds as soon as you display your dialog & then execute your function. If the user clicks your button, you can stop your timer.

```
Timer _timer;
bool userResponded = false;
```

You will need a `StatefulWidget` & wherever you show your dialog, you need to start the timer.

```
showDialog(...); // Your showDialog method
// You have to update userResponded to true if user clicks on your dialog or whatever
// It should look something like this: setState(() => userResponded = true);

_timer = Timer(const Duration(seconds: 10), () { // Start your timer for x seconds
  if (!userResponded) { // If user didn't respond
    // execute your function
  }
});
```

Also, you need to override the `onDispose` method & stop the timer:

```
@override
void onDispose() {
  _timer?.cancel();
  super.onDispose();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but is it also possible to run in a class without state?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend running a `Timer` in a `StatelessWidget` (class without state). The reason why I am recommending a `StatefulWidget` is that you get a `dispose` method to prevent memory leaks.

Comment: Hmmm...that causes a design challenge for me though.  What if I call  ` _timer?.cancel ` right after the timer finishes or if the user clicks ok?  Is it still unsafe?

Comment: No, that will work perfectly fine. You can do that. But then, you need to start `Timer` before you show your dialog.

Comment: got it.  Thanks.  Marked as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you would use a Timer widget.

Timer example:

```
Timer _timer = Timer(
  const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
  () {
    // Call some function after delay of 500ms
  },
);
```

To cancel the timer, use `_timer.cancel();`

So, most likely in the initState method you'll want to set timer object, then when the user presses the button, you can cancel this timer which means the callback in it won't run after a delay you've specified.